# Making individual histograms for multiple categories from one sheet in R

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, histogram

I have a data set with multiple categories of study type for pond data. The column of overall categories is organized with each type having individual values that follow. I can make a histogram for each when I produce individual sheets to use. I have dug around for a while, but cannot find how to make the same histogram for the study types from the overall data set.

[Piece of data sheet that I am working with. As you can see, there are multiple study types that we have each with their own data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7kUY.png)

Basically, I want to pull each individual study type and the num_divided to make a histogram for the types. My end goal is to make one image with the 9 different histograms stacked above one another. Each having the same x-axis values and their individual names on the left-hand side.

The trouble I am running into is that when I make the histograms from the separated sheets, I cannot make the stacked image I want. I apologize in advance if this lacks some information, but I also thank anyone that offers advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ggplot2` is the best option.
You didn't give reproducible data but it's easy to make some. Here are 9 studies each with 100 values:

```
set.seed(111)
dat <- data.frame(study = rep(letters[1:9], each = 100), num_divided = rnorm(900))
```

What you want is a facetted plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = num_divided)) + geom_histogram() + facet_grid(study ~ .)
```

[image]

If you don't know much about `ggplot2`, a good starting point is [the R Cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/).